# google indexing

Tags: indexing, google-search

I have a question, how can I have a similar google result than wikipedia, myspace, ...

When you search wikipedia on google, you have below the result an input search for wikipedia, which is friendly for the user. When you search Myspace on google, you have below the google result, some links: Login, register, Sign up ,Search...

I really want to have this kind of result for my website on google.

Is it posssible to do the same thing with Yahoo Search and Bing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sitemap: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Create a custom search engine: http://www.google.com/cse/

Thanks Google!

Comment: Thanks Pierre! what about the input search? How can I enable it?

Comment: search wikipedia on google and see the first result, you will know what i'm talking about input search.

Comment: I know what you mean. If it doesn't work with custom search engine (I didn't test it), I think you will have to set a deal with google.